# jQuery Difference between $('#one').add('#two') and $('#one, #two')

Tags: jquery

Is there any benefit to the former over the latter, unless perhaps you were chaining a set of commands which meant that it was necessary to add an element mid way through the chain?

Comment: @MackieeE Assuming that's a typo...

Comment: I think you understood it right. As such, there's no difference, but there might be cases where you need to use the latter, while in some cases you can simply go with the first one.

Comment: FWIW, `$("#one, #two")` appears to be slightly faster, if you're in a position to select either of them.  http://jsperf.com/add-vs-multiple-selectors

Comment: Use the one that makes the most sense for the situation. Given the code in your title (code in title? that really should be in your question...), the latter makes more sense.

Comment: @PatrickQ http://jsperf.com/add-vs-multiple-selectors check results again i tested it on IE11 and Chrome 33+ .Results are opposite ??

Comment: @TusharGupta Interesting. The second option is consistently faster for me in FF28.

Comment: @PatrickQ yeah i tested in Firefox28  too it is faster .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#one, #two')` is same as `$('#one').add('#two')`

When you a cached selector

[.add( jQuery object )](https://api.jquery.com/add/#add-jQuery-object)

```
var el = $('#one');
//you can do
el.add('#two');
// or
$('#two').add(el);
//Or
el.find('.el').add('#two');
```

Answer (score 1):

They have the same function. I think the difference is just the order, for manipulations. For example:

```
$('#one').css('background','red').add('#two').fadeOut();
```

And:

```
$('#one,#two').css('background','red').fadeOut();
```

The first example will set just the `#one` with red text, then fade out both. The second example will set both with red text, then fade out both. You can set your own flux for effects and returns.